# add dynamic id property to an object's keys

Tags: javascript

Let's say we have an class like:

```
 function Parent() {
    this.pool = []
 }

 Parent.prototype.addChild = function(instance) {
    instance.id = this.pool.length + 1;
    this.pool.push(instance);

    return this;
 };

 Parent.prototype.removeChild = function(index) {
    this.pool.splice(index, 1);
 };

 function Child() {
      //something
 }
```

So, my implimentation would be:

```
var task = new Parent(),
    child = new Child(),
    child2 = new Child(),
    child3 = new Child(),
    child4 = new Child();
task.addChild(child).addChild(child2).addChild(child3).addChild(child4);
```

add this point if we console.log task.pool, it would display and collection of objects with id 1,2,3,4.

So let's remove 3:

```
tasks.removeChild(2);
```

Now the tasks.pool would display the collection but 1,2,4.

How can create an id by reference, meaning, if I remove 3, then 4 would change to 3, so we keep the numberical order without any gap?

Comment: Give the `Child` an `id` property for reference, and key off of that when removing.

Comment: use id as getter and calculate index

Comment: @Marc he's already doing that in `addChild` (the `instance.id` field).  What's not happening is fixing up any following IDs when one gets removed.

Comment: What should be id of `child` in `task.addChild(child).addChild(child);`?

Comment: I suspect this is an example of the X/Y problem: What is it you're *really* trying to achieve? Why do `Child` objects need to know their position in `pool`?

Comment: I agree with T.J.Crowder - the fact you're needing to do this implies some design flaw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can create an id by reference, meaning, if I remove 3, then 4 would change to 3, so we keep the numberical order without any gap?

To do that, you'd either:

1. Loop through the pool after making the change, updating the `Child` `id`s, or
2. Give the `Child` instances a reference to the pool and have them dynamically generate their `id` value (e.g., using a getter function) based on where they are in the pool

#1 would be more efficient in terms of `id` lookup. #2 might be less prone to implementation errors (e.g., doing an operation on the pool and forgetting to update the `id` values). But it also increases the coupling between `Child` and `Parent`, which is generally not a good idea.

**Live example of #1**:

```js
var Parent = (function() { // To give us a private scope for utility funcs
  function Parent() {
    this.pool = []
  }

  Parent.prototype.addChild = function(instance) {
    instance.id = this.pool.length + 1;
    this.pool.push(instance);

    return this;
  };

  Parent.prototype.removeChild = function(index) {
    this.pool.splice(index, 1);
    fixupIds(this.pool);
  };

  function fixupIds(pool) {
    pool.forEach(function(instance, index) {
      instance.id = index + 1;
    });
  }

  return Parent;
})();

function Child() {
  //something
}

var task = new Parent(),
  child = new Child(),
  child2 = new Child(),
  child3 = new Child(),
  child4 = new Child();
task.addChild(child).addChild(child2).addChild(child3).addChild(child4);
snippet.log(JSON.stringify(task, null, 2));
task.removeChild(2);
snippet.log(JSON.stringify(task, null, 2));
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="//tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

I didn't do a live example of #2. Frankly I really, really wouldn't do it that way. :-) But if you did, you'd use `Object.defineProperty` to define an `id` property on the `Child.prototype` that looked the child up in the pool (the child would have to know about its pool).

Comment: IMHO, the Child objects should be able to exist independently of the pool, and therefore have no knowledge of where in the pool they sit

Comment: @Alnitak: I completely agree.

Comment: @vp_arth it does, but that logic exists in the pool code, not within the `Child` (which just gets "monkey patched" with the ID)

Comment: this patches will not work, if we can have duplicate entries(see comment above) or even reuse child in several pools. :) I vote for `Parent.indexOf(Child)` method..

Comment: @vp_arth: **If**, yes. [I think this is all by-the-bye, though](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33923257/add-dynamic-id-property-to-an-objects-keys/33923339?noredirect=1#comment55607918_33923257).

Answer (score 1):

You could just assign an id when the child is added and then remove it by filtering the existing children rather than coupling the child's id to its index in the `pool` array:

```
function Parent() {
    this.pool = [];
    this._idCount = 0;
 }

 Parent.prototype.addChild = function(instance) {
    instance.id = this._idCount;
    this._idCount += 1;
    this.pool.push(instance);

    return this;
 };

 Parent.prototype.removeChild = function(id) {
    this.pool = this.pool.filter(function(child) {
      return child.id !== id;
    });
 };

 function Child() {
      //something
 }
```

Alternatively, you could have `removeChild` accept a child object instead of an id then you could easily find and remove the child using `indexOf` and `splice` or by using `filter`.

You could also avoid mutating the children altogether by using a `Map` to relate your child instances to their generated ids. This would enable multiple children to be added to multiple parents without id conflicts:

```
function Parent() {
    this.pool = [];
    this.idMap = new Map();
    this._idCount = 0;
 }

 Parent.prototype.addChild = function(instance) {
    this.idMap.set(this._idCount, instance);
    this._idCount++;
    this.pool.push(instance);

    return this;
 };

 Parent.prototype.removeChild = function(id) {
    var index = this.pool.indexOf(this.idMap.get(id));
    if(index !== -1) {
      this.idMap.delete(id);
      this.pool.splice(index, 1);
    }
 };

 function Child() {
      //something
 }
```